# How do I read in a .txt file onto an array of integers?

Tags: arrays, c, file, clang, ascii

I have been able to read in a txt file and place each individual int onto an array and this is the closest I've come to succeeding.

```
int main(){
    int key[100];
    int ch;

    gp = fopen("C:\\file.txt","r");
 
    if (gp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not printing");
        exit(0);
    }
 
    ch= fgetc(gp);
    while (ch != EOF) {
 
        if(isdigit(ch)) {
            key[i] = ch;
            i++;
        }
        ch = fgetc(gp);
    }
}
```

With this code I was able to read in each individual number from the file as a character, and successfully print the array.  The problem is, I need to be able to access the value of the arrays, and it was storing in the ascii values of the chars.

To fix this, I attempted just subtracting 48 from the chars before assigning the value of ch onto the array, to try to compensate.  Like so:

```
while (ch != EOF) {

    if(isdigit(ch)) {
        key[i] = ch-48;
        i++;
    }
    ch = fgetc(gp);
}
```

Or letting that loop run and trying in another one.

```
while (ch != EOF) {

    if(isdigit(ch)) {
        key[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }
    ch = fgetc(gp);
}
for(i=0;i<strlen(key);i++){
    key[i] = key[i]-48;
}
```

Needless to say, those attempts also didn't work.

My last attempt was trying `fscanf(gp, "%d", key);`, though this only seemed to work for my first integer.  running `fscanf` through a loop doesn't seem to work either.

```
for (i=0; i <strlen(key); i++){
    fscanf(gp, "%d", key);
}
```

So the .txt file that I'm scanning in, looks like this:

```
4
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 8 8 7 
9 0 8 4
```

Comment: What is the contents of `C:\\file.txt`? `for (i = 0; i < (int)(sizeof(key) / sizeof(*key)) && fscanf(gp, "%d", &key[i]) == 1; i++);` may be what you want.

Comment: Why are you using `fgetc()`, designed for reading a `char`, when you want an `int`? Also, can you include a sample of the file you're trying to read in your question? (Not in a comment, but by making an [edit] to your post;)

Comment: @MikeCAT it is just a file with integers 0 < i <10.

Comment: Tip: `exit(0)` means everything worked out fine (no error) but what you really mean is it had trouble, so `exit(-1)` is more appropriate. Since you're in `main()` you can just `return -1`, even easier. `exit()` is reserved for situations when you're not in `main()`.

Comment: When you say they 'didn't work', in what way didn't they work?  What did they give you that was unexpected?  To convert an ascii digit to its value, it is better (for readability) to subtract `'0'` rather than `48`, though they are exactly the same in effect

Comment: @ChrisDodd funnily enough, I tried the old code but with '0' instead of 48, and that seemed to do the trick!  I then went back to 48, and that seemed to be working this time, too.  Oops!